# Start a new explorer.exe process from C#

Tags: c#, process, windows-explorer, child-process

If I run this command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}\::{2227A280-3AEA-1069-A2DE-08002B30309D}"
```

from the Windows shell (via <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), my printer and faxes open in a *new* `explorer.exe` process. (So I have 2 running `explorer.exe` processes.)

If i execute:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe", @"::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\" + 
                                          @"::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}\" + 
                                          @"::{2227A280-3AEA-1069-A2DE-08002B30309D}");
```

from a C# program, my printer and faxes open too, but as an child process of the main `explorer.exe` process (the one running the Windows shell, including the taskbar, etc.).

What can I do to start a second `explorer.exe` process with the printer and faxes window from C#?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you have a few unescaped `\\` in your second string.

Comment: ohu, your right.. but that's only because I wrote this on the fly, in my real code its escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial thoughts - check your "Launch folder windows in a separate process" in Folder Options (Organize -> Folder & Search Options -> View tab). This is unchecked by default, hence "Check" this and try your C# code again.

I know this setting affects the ShellExecute function but I am not sure if .NET's Diagnostic namespace uses the same route.

ShellExecute(handle, "explore", , NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

---

Second thoughts - a similar issue has been already discussed in stackoverflow and this post might give you some idea.

[Start new process, without being a child of the spawning process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434379/start-new-process-without-being-a-child-of-the-spawning-process)

Comment: Just as an FYI, `Process.Start` does use `ShellExecute` by default, though it can be made to use `CreateProcess` instead if you use one of the overloads that takes a `ProcessStartInfo`.

Comment: Thats true. By default the ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute is set to true.