# Change from one Unity app (.exe) to another Unity app (.exe)

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to change from one Unity app to another? I am not talking about scene changing but the whole application itself. Like:
(a) Changing from Game_1.exe to Game_2.exe
(b) Changing from Game_1.apk to Game_2.apk

Comment: you can probably spawn one process and close the current..what have you tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434379/start-new-process-without-being-a-child-of-the-spawning-process

Comment: But can I keep the first process keep running while switching to another? I am sorry but all i could find was scene switching.

Comment: It should be noted that the unity exe file is bitwise identical from one application to another (with, at most, some internal strings changed based on what name you gave it) and all the operational code that actually is your game is inside the `Xyz_Data` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch a new process (e.g .exe) by using the `process.Start()`method, as explained in the [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8)

Example from the above docs:

```cs
using (Process myProcess = new Process())
{
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.Start();
}
```