# setsid equivalent in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, fork

I'm trying to start a process detached. `Process.start()` works, but when the parent process quits, the child process will be killed.

In Linux people call `setsid()` to start a new session, so the child process will stay alive if parent process dies. What's the equivalent solution in Windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start new process, without being a child of the spawning process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434379/start-new-process-without-being-a-child-of-the-spawning-process)

Answer (score 0):

use CreateProcess() with dwCreationFlags set to DETACHED_PROCESS.