# Start a separate Process without printing its output to Console and terminating it when the program ends

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, .net-6.0

I have the following .NET (Core) 6 code to open a folder in VS Code in Windows (my app doesn't need to run on other environments):

```cs
    public void OpenInVsCode()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Opening folder in VS Code: " + this.Folder);

        var procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("code.exe", this.Folder)
        {
            // These 3 lines don't seem to matter
            RedirectStandardOutput = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = false,
            RedirectStandardError = false,
            // This line should solve the problem but it doesn't
            UseShellExecute = true,
        };
        Process.Start(procInfo);
    }
```

VS Code does start. However it starts printing its output into my console app and when my Console app closes, VS Code is closed as well, which seems contradicting to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64300073/653457).

[image]

How do I start a totally separated Process?

---

Update: It seems strange that in my Console app if it ends by itself (i.e. reaches to the last line), the app stops and will not close VS Code even if I close the finished Console window. However if the app stays open (due to `Console.ReadLine` or `await Task.Delay`) and I close it by closing the Console window or pressing Ctrl + C, VS Code is terminated.

Comment: Imho. UseShellExecute schuld do the Job.. could you try this: var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("code.exe", this.Folder);
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(startInfo);

Comment: @Starbax I tried but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Not sure if object initializer and constructor work well together in this case. You could try:
var procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
procInfo.FileName = "code.exe";
procInfo.Arguments = this.Folder;
procInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

Comment: Opening Notepad++ works just fine for me via .Net 5 console app/ winForms app: 
var procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("\"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\"") { UseShellExecute = true };
            
            Process.Start(procInfo); 

Maybe you can try this call, without arguments, first.

Comment: Unfortunately the first suggestion didn't work. I can open Notepad++ and it doesn't get closed when my app exits and even if I pass a parameter, that's interesting.